# More than one set of choices before submitting form

Tags: forms, asp-classic

I have been tasked with creating an email form in old ASP that users can book onto an event. Is there a way whereby if they wanted to book on more than one event, say three events that they could select out three different choice without having to resubmit the form three times, and submit just once

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, could you not just use multiple form inputs with a type of 'checkbox'?